# Blue Snowball iCE Microphone not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, usb, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I recently purchased a [Blue Snowball iCE microphone](http://www.bluemic.com/snowball_iCE/). It seems like this [person](https://scottlinux.com/2012/07/23/blue-snowball-usb-mic-linux-compatible/) and this [person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244295/does-blue-microphones-snowball-ice-work-with-ubuntu-12-04) had success using this on earlier versions of Ubuntu. When I plug in this microphone, it's not recognized at all.  I plugged into my Windows 7 box, and it works just fine. Below I have the outputs for running dmesg and lsbusb -v. I love the quality of the mic, can anyone help!

When I run dmesg, I see this message:

```
[ 9398.403809] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[ 9408.410102] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0005
[ 9408.410108] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9408.410111] usb 3-1: Product: Blue Snowball 
[ 9408.410502] usb 3-1: can't set config #1, error -32
```

I have been googling around to figure out what that error could mean, and no luck.

When I run lsbusb -v, I get the following related to the mic:

```
Bus 003 Device 024: ID 0d8c:0005 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        16
  idVendor           0x0d8c C-Media Electronics, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0005 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          159
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength           46
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0001
          Left Front (L)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             7
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               8
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (SELECTOR_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 8
        bNrInPins               1
        baSource( 0)           10
        iSelector               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                10
        bSourceID               2
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x03
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x00
        iFeature                0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           7
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                29
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             1
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            7 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]         8000
        tSamFreq[ 1]        11025
        tSamFreq[ 2]        16000
        tSamFreq[ 3]        22050
        tSamFreq[ 4]        32000
        tSamFreq[ 5]        44100
        tSamFreq[ 6]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0064  1x 100 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      26
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

This is the output from syslog:

```
Aug  9 00:30:54 Europa kernel: [  835.548792] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Aug  9 00:31:04 Europa mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5"
Aug  9 00:31:04 Europa mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Aug  9 00:31:04 Europa kernel: [  845.631082] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0005
Aug  9 00:31:04 Europa kernel: [  845.631088] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug  9 00:31:04 Europa kernel: [  845.631091] usb 2-1.5: Product: Blue Snowball 
Aug  9 00:31:04 Europa kernel: [  845.631450] usb 2-1.5: can't set config #1, error -32
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/244295/does-blue-microphones-snowball-ice-work-with-ubuntu-12-04 (see dobey's question about `pavucontrol` directly under OP), and related to a fair number of google search results. Please acknowledge.

Comment: I have installed pulse audio control (pavucontrol) but because the device is not recognized, alsamixer and subsequently pavucontrol is not seeing the device.  The biggest clue I have is the "was not an MTP Device".

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 15.10 and I see error -32 with my blue snowball mic on USB 2.0 ports, and error -71 on USB 3.0 ports. I know I got this mic to work on ubuntu previously, I think a kernel update may have broken something. I am trying to track this down as well.

Comment: Thanks Afforess!  I was thinking it was a kernel issue.  Please let me know what you find out!

Comment: @ChrisB.Anilao I did fix it, and it was totally unrelated to the kernel or OS. I changed out the USB cord, thinking that might be the problem, but when I investigated more closely, I found that 2 of the 4 pins in the back of the snowball 'usb type b jack' were crushed against the back. I used some tiny pliers and straightened the pins out and made sure all 4 pins plugged in, and my device was recognized. [(A pic from mine to show the 4 pins)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pung3yxsbr9yc7/2015-08-09%2021.02.47.jpg?dl=0). The pins were really soft and easy to crush accidentally.

Comment: @Afforess where is the big plastic guide in the middle?  Did you take it out?  I attached a link to picture of a type b jack: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61V5wWC9QdL._SX522_.jpg

Comment: @ChrisB.Anilao The plastic guide fell out - I put it back in. The pins sit partially in the plastic guide, but they want to bend out of it. I was careful to make sure the USB cable did not cause the pins to come back out.

The construction of the usb jack in the snowball feels really cheap, I have taped the USB cable to the back, so it can not come free again. Not ideal, but I suspect if I have to bend the pins much more, they will break.

Comment: @Afforess my usb jack seems to be fine.  I went to my windows box and plugged it in and it works perfectly.  As for my Ubuntu box, it's still not working at all.  I pulled down 15.04 on to a bootable usb drive and tried to see if that version would detect the blue snowball... no luck.  Are you on 64 bit or 32?  I tried both on different computers and none could detect the mic.

Comment: @ChrisB.Anilao Interesting. I am using 64bit. I looked up the error codes, and -32  is defined as  `EPIPE           32      /* Broken pipe */`      in the kernel. , which hints that this is a communication problem. It is interesting that your OS does seem to detect the device type & name correctly, from the lsusb output. I will dump the lsusb -v output of my working snowball and see if there are any differences in the detected device when I get home.

Comment: @Afforess if you are able to, could you post the rules files in /etc/udev/rules.d.  I think you have a line in there I need to detect the microphone :)  Thanks for your help dude.  I really do appreciated it.

Comment: @ChrisB.Anilao Lets [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26818/discussion-between-afforess-and-chris-b-anilao).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blue Snowball iCE **DOES NOT WORK** with Ubuntu 14.04 out of the box.  If you looking for a microphone for your Ubuntu 14.04 box, don't buy this one.  I bought the ATR2100 by Audio-Technica and that worked very well.

If you want to the Blue Snowball, I recommend getting the original version (not the iCE)  I haven't tried it, but after talking to a number of folks, the original seemed to be working for them.